# vscode multiple terminals configuration issue

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was reading with new features of vscode 1.9, adding/working with multiple terminals, however I ended up with adding multiple terminals of same type. e.g. cmd.
Is there way I can option to choose what type of terminal I can use, either bash(git), cmd (windows) OR bash(Ubuntu)?  So following dropdown of vscode terminal should change as:

[image]

1. cmd.exe
2. bash.exe (Git)
3. bash.exe (Ubuntu)

I tried to change setting.json file for `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows"`, however it considers only last value.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is currently not possible. There is an open feature request about it in the backlog however: [#10893](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10893)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Start any shell](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=remcoros.startanyshell).

Other option would be to open the desired shell from inside the default shell. Easier if you have all the desired ones in your path.

Answer (score 0):

In 2017 when the question was posted it was really not possible. Now this has been addressed already by using terminal profiles - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles.

Example configuration:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
  "Cmd": {
    "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "icon": "terminal-cmd"
  },
  "GitBash": {
    "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe", "icon": "terminal-bash",
    "icon": "terminal-bash"
  },
  "PowerShell": {
    "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
    "icon": "terminal-powershell"
  },
},
```